# How to run OSX Character Viewer from Java Swing app

Tags: java, macos, swing, fonts

I have seen a few OSX apps that have a **Special Characters** menu item in their Edit menu. For example **Safari**.

Clicking it brings up the so-called **Character Viewer**.

How can this be achieved by a Java Swing app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac OS X 10.8 you'll find the Character Viewer app here:

```
/System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app
```

I think the easiest way to run this from a Java app is by using executing the process:

```
new ProcessBuilder("/System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app/Contents/MacOS/CharacterPalette").start();
```

Comment: Thanks Steve Mcleod. I'm a little concerned about the 'hard coding' of the path but it works on my iMac. Maybe the path is held somewhere 'soft'...

Answer (score 1):

[`FontShower`](http://mindprod.com/applet/fontshower.html) is an applet that displays a list of available fonts, including the installed [*logical*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) fonts, and a selection of available glyphs, sizes and colors.